# Trigger.io Keystore File not found

Tags: keystore, trigger.io

I successfully created a keystore file using,

keytool -genkey -v -keystore arun_release_key.keystore
-alias my_key -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

I got my keystore, in "C:\Users\kp\Desktop\forge-tools-3.3.2\forge-tools" named as arun_release_key.keystore

Now, When i do "forge package android",
First is it would ask for "The location of your keystore"
The problem is here, i type the location as in "C:\Users\kp\Desktop\forge-tools-3.3.2\forge-tools"
Failed to load the keystore is the error i get.
again, tried without quotes and tried typing only the file name that is arun_release_key.keystore.

Any solution for this problem m facing?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting it explicitly in your local_config.json?  Mine looks like this (on Ubuntu) -

```
"android": {
    "sdk": "/home/kkrause/Documents/android-sdk-linux",
    "profiles": {
        "DEFAULT": {
            "keystore": "/home/kkrause/Documents/camosites/camomedia.keystore",
            "keyalias": "camomedia"
        }
    }
}
```

On Windows it would be something like this (note the backslash escapes) -

```
"android": {
    "sdk": "C:\\home\\kkrause\\Documents\\android-sdk-windows",
    "profiles": {
        "DEFAULT": {
            "keystore": "C:\\home\\kkrause\\Documents\\camosites\\camomedia.keystore",
            "keyalias": "camomedia"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your alias name, password is all correct. I found that I had screwed up my alias_name and it didn't work.